How to set default value of a model field to another field of same mode in django
I've created a Student model in django project with has a field named "enrollmentdate" and "paymentdate" now i need to save "paymentdate" as default value in "enrollmentdate"
my model code is as under,
> ```
class Student(models.Model):
fname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
lname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
password=models.CharField(max_length=100)
contactno = models.CharField(max_length=100)
address = models.TextField()
grade=models.CharField(max_length=100)
enrollmentstartdate=models.DateField()
enrollmentenddate=models.DateField()
daysremaining=models.IntegerField()
feespaid=models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
paymentdate=models.DateField()  
> ```

how  can i do this?
thanks in advance
I have tried
entrollmentdate=models.DateField(default=paymentdate)
but not works

what do you mean by default values? there are auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True and default=timezone.now (or any other time you prefer)
you can also read more about them here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField

You can achieve this by overriding the save() method of your model.
class Student(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contactno = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.TextField()
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    enrollmentstartdate = models.DateField()
    enrollmentenddate = models.DateField()
    daysremaining = models.IntegerField()
    feespaid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    paymentdate = models.DateField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.enrollmentstartdate:  
            self.enrollmentstartdate = self.paymentdate  
        super(Student, self).save(*args, **kwargs)  

Whenever you save a Student object and the enrollmentstartdate is not provided, it will default to the value of paymentdate.

You can add override the save function in your model
if u didnt add enrollmentsdate manual the function will add paymentdate :
class Student(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contactno = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.TextField()
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    enrollmentstartdate = models.DateField()
    enrollmentenddate = models.DateField()
    daysremaining = models.IntegerField()
    feespaid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    paymentdate = models.DateField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.enrollmentstartdate:  
            self.enrollmentstartdate = self.paymentdate  
        super(Student, self).save(*args, **kwargs)  


Now one more question, how can i auto add entrollmentenddate to 365 days after entrollmentstartdate ???

You are welcome
Just try it :
import datetime
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
if not self.enrollmentstartdate:
self.enrollmentstartdate = self.paymentdate
if not self. entrollmentenddate :
self.entrollmentenddate = entrollmentstartdate + datetime.timedelta(days=365)
super(Student, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

I will make new answer to you to can explain it well

You can add override the save function in your model if u didnt add enrollmentsdate manual the function will add paymentdate and dont forget to make  enrollmentdate and enrollmentstartdate null=True, blank=True:
import datetime
class Student(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contactno = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.TextField()
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    enrollmentstartdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    enrollmentenddate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    daysremaining = models.IntegerField()
    feespaid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    paymentdate = models.DateField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.enrollmentstartdate:  
            self.enrollmentstartdate = self.paymentdate
        if not self. entrollmentenddate : 
            self.entrollmentenddate = entrollmentstartdate + datetime.timedelta(days=365) 
        super(Student, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

